# How to play .asf and .xesc video file on website?

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I have two different video files. One is of .asf format and another is of .xesc format. How can I play these video files on my website?

Comment: Before posting a question, you should have done the proper research and made attempts to solve your issue yourself. Then, if you get stuck on something _specific_, come back and show us your attempt. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can't unless you also program your own customized decoders. Easiest thing is to just... Convert them to browser compatible format (_example:_ MP4 video) and display using the Answer posted below. Try searching in Google for `online video converter` to do a test conversion into MP4.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to upload it to a video-streaming service (such as YouTube) and play it on your website as an embed video. Then you do not have to worry about streaming the video - which can drag the speed of your entire website down.

However you can also convert the video to a supported HTML5 format and upload it to your server and use HTML5 builtin video player (not recommended).

You should use the `video` tag - HTML5 feature

```
<video height="500" width="500" controls>
    <source src="source/of/the/video/" type="video/type" />
    Can't play this video right now...
</video>
```

If you do not want to convert it, you may want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4102048/1527252)

Comment: I tried this way. But it doesn't support .asf and .xesc video format. Is there any way that I can play them on my website?

Comment: @KaziMd.Munim check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4102048/1527252)